# Prometheus - relabel_configs, regex expresion, fetch data from target url

Tags: regex, prometheus

I am trying to fetch from target url information about api version and add it to the metric.

**Sample target url**: https://domain/v1_2_5_0/api/version

**Expectation**: api_version1: 'v1_2_5_0', api_version2: 'https://domain/v1_2_5_0/api/version'

**Result**: api_version2: 'https://domain/v1_2_5_0/api/version'

config:

```
relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: api_version1
        regex: (v[0-9_]+)
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: api_version2
        regex: (.*)
```

Only label 'api_version2' appears in the Prometheus metric.
I am interested if anyone knows why api_verison1 doesn't work and how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed regex: `(^.*\/(v[0-9_]+).*$)`, now it is working as expected.